# How do I update a custom JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, repaint

If I call the `repaint()` function on my custom `JPanel`, my understanding is that it re executes `paintComponent(Graphics g)` correct? or do it recreate the whole `JPanel`? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: See [*A Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html), and try to focus on a _specific_ question.

Answer (score 4):

+1 to trashgod. 
The docs for [`repaint()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29) state:

> Repaints this component.

`repaint()` causes AWT to invoke `update()` (for heavyweight components which will then invoke paint`()`) or `paint()` (for lightweight components) on EDT which in-turn invokes `paintComponent(...)`.

so no it is not re-created every time `repaint()` is called.

**Reference:**

- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [A Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html)

Comment: +1 In a round about way, the event queue in there some where, but the idea is sound ;)